# How can I see if my unposted question (or answer) is saved?

Tags: support, questions, posting

I am not a native English speaker (and probably a lot of SO users aren't either), and when I read some of my questions a few times, maybe later, especially if the question was written when I was tired, I discover a lot of mistakes and also at worst truncated sentences. Because of this I prefer whenever possible to read the question again before posting. Because I keep it unposted to read it later, loosing its content is a concern.

I observed accidentally that the browser saves the form in case the browser closes unexpectedly, I suppose this is a feature of Stackoverflow.

Is it possible to see for sure if the form containing my question is saved, in case the browser closes for some reason?

Comment: By opening up another browser and clicking on the "Ask Question" link... you may want to turn this into a feature request to show you when your question was last "saved" or some such thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you write an answer, Stack Exchange saves a draft after X minutes. When this happens, Stack Exchange gives you the "draft saved" message right under the text area used to enter the answer text; it is visible until you don't press a key on your keyboard to continue to write your answer.

> [image: screenshot]

Then, the "discard" link is shown close to the "Post Your Answer" button.

> [image: screenshot]

This happens to questions you write too. When you see the "discard" link after the "Post Your Question" button, you know a draft has been saved on the server.

As far as I can see, the "discard" link appears about a minute after you started to write a post; I am sure it appears only after you write X characters, but I cannot tell you what is the minimum number of characters your post needs to contain.

Comment: You're so meta :-).